# how do I dispose chewie() video player widget

Tags: dart, flutter

how do I dispose chewie widget. I have this but don't know how to stop the video from playing when I leave the page

```
   Chewie(
   VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile),
   autoInitialize: true,
   cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **WillPopScope** widget. using that widget you can process anything before leaving the Screen and in your case you can stop the video. below example help you to .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  int counter = 0 ;

  void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    ));
  }

  class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Vounter Value '),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Launch Second screen'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
  }

  class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


    _willPopScope(){
      counter = counter + 1;
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _willPopScope() ,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Second Screen"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!' + counter.toString() ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```